# Can't get drafts with WP_Query using post_status parameter

Tags: wp-query, loop, post-status

I can't seem to get drafts to show up with WP_Query, even when post_status is set to 'any' or 'draft'

```
        $args = array(
                    'p' => 1234, 
                    'post_type' => 'any',
                    'post_status' => 'any'
                    );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            // display the post
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();
```

If I go back and Publish post 1234, WP_Query grabs it just fine. But when it is a draft, neither `any` nor `draft` grabs it.

I read that the `exclude_from_search` parameter in `register_post_type()` prevents posts from showing up with WP_Query, so I set it to false in the post_type I am grabbing from, like so:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => '',
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'menu_position' => 60,
    'menu_icon' => null,
    'capability_type' => post,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'revisions'),
    'rewrite' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
);

register_post_type('chart', $args);
```

Is there something I'm overlooking here? I don't see why a draft post in this post type wouldn't show up in the query above.

Comment: what do you get if you `print_r( $query )`? I wonder if `have_posts()` or `the_post()` is preventing drafts from showing up...

Comment: Here's the result of printing the query: http://pastebin.com/MpZK2vPf

Comment: And that's a `print_r()` on `$query`?!? It looks like it's not querying...see my answer.

Comment: Have you tried swapping `p` with `post__in`?

Comment: Your query-- the first one in your question-- works for me with a couple of different post types. I suspect that you have a plugin or something in your theme that is manipulating your queries in a way that is breaking this one. Disable your plugins and switch to the default theme and see what happens.

Comment: @supertrue did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

Try passing it as an array.

**For example**

```
$args = array(
    'p' => 1234, 
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'post_status' => array('draft')
);
```

**Or for all types**

```
$args = array(
    'p' => 1234, 
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash')
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. According to the codex and trac, post_status should accept a string, array, or comma-separated string equally well.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me, when I need to get pending and drafts. Thanks

Comment: I just did a test with 4.7.2 with the 'post_type' as an array of 'any', and a text string of 'any' [so
    'post_type' => array('any')
    'post_type' => 'any'
] and both parameters were able to get draft posts

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this exact scenario.  In my opinion it *should* work, but when I tried a combination of `'p' => 123` and `'post_status' => 'any'`, it would *not* return the post if the post status is draft.

I was able to work around this by using `'post__in' => array( 123 )` instead.  So:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array( 123 ),
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'post_status' => 'any',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
// ... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have an odd bug going on. Try replacing the oneline `WP_Query` with the following:

```
$query = new WP_Query();
$posts = $query->query( $args );
```

Comment: Should I then also change $query to $posts in `$query->have_posts()` and `$query->the_post()`?

Comment: Yep, though you could name my `$query` to `$my_query` and my `$posts` to `$query` and it wouldn't make much difference. Basically the issue I'm trying to circumvent is the failure of the query to process...actually, where did you put that `print_r()` you did?

Comment: I put it after WP_Query and before the loop, like this: `$query = new WP_Query( $args ); print_r($query); while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();`.

Comment: Yea, try calling the `query()` method and see how that goes.

Comment: Any solution to this?